# FTP With FileZilla, WAMP, and CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, ftp, filezilla

Ok, so I need to download files from my server since they are files that users upload.  The reason I am using FTP with WAMP is just so I can test my script on my computer.  Once I get it working, I can change the config files once the app is uploaded to a web server.  I am using FileZilla.

MY application installation folder:
W:\wamp\www\idealeffort

The above directory is also set as my FileZilla user's home directory.  There is a folder in my application called "_resumes".  These are the files that I will need to download.  So here is the script that I use to download these files.

```
                $this->load->library('ftp');

                $this->ftp->connect();

                $this->ftp->download('/_resumes/'.$app['resume_filename'], FCPATH.'_resumes/'.$app['resume_filename']);
```

$app['resume_filename'] is a database result.  I have checked to make sure that the file exists.  I get the error "Unable to download the specified file. Please check your path."

Any ideas?

Note:  FCPATH displays as "W:\wamp\www\idealeffort\ "

Answer (score 1):

If you check [codeigniter help](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/ftp.html)
you have to give path from /public_html/....

So i think its problem with path.

Hope this helps

Comment: No, it does not help.  I know it's a problem with the paths.  I don't know what the problem is.  Why do you think I listed the directories?

Comment: And there is no public html folder.  It's just my wamp/www/idealeffort

Comment: I am asking you to change directly path from /_resumes to starting from your root folder like /public_html/project_name/_resume

Comment: try /idealeffort/_resume

Comment: The home directory of the FTP user is W:\wamp\www\idealeffort.  The "_resumes" directory is in that folder.

Comment: I am not sure but you can check with "\" instead of "/" probably that could be creating a problem because of operating system.

Comment: Can you check by setting Debug true in config file for ftp that what error message you get?